# VB.net ByVal and ByRef doesnt work

Tags: vb.net, authentication

So i have a couple of subs and i want to share variables between them... I'm new to programming and i don't understand how to use ByVal and ByRef. I'm trying to make a login page.

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click (ByRef BlnCorrectPassword As Boolean, ByRef BlnCorrectLogin As Boolean)


    If blncorrectlogin = True And blncorrectpassword = True Then
        MsgBox("This part is still being developed!") ' I will make this form close and open a new form.
    Else
        MsgBox("The login or password is incorrect, please try again.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim BlnCorrectLogin As Boolean

    If TextBox1.Text = "login" Then
        BlnCorrectLogin = True

    End If
End Sub

Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged
    Dim BlnCorrectPassword As Boolean

    If TextBox1.Text = "password" Then
        BlnCorrectPassword = True

    End If
   End Sub
 End Class
```

Comment: I'm amazed if that even compiles

Comment: ByVal and ByRef just define how a variable is passed as an argument to a sub (i.e. are you passing just the variables value or are you passing a reference to the original variable?).  Can you please elaborate on what specific problem you are encountering?  The ByVal vs ByRef dichotomy doesn't seem applicable to the code you've posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dramatically reduce the complexity if the username and password are checked in a sub and only check them on the button click event. You don't need to check if they're correct every time someone changes the values of the textboxes.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click

    If CheckLoginDetails() = True Then
        MsgBox("This part is still being developed!") ' I will make this form close and open a new form.
    Else
        MsgBox("The login or password is incorrect, please try again.")
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CheckLoginDetails() As Boolean
    If TextBox1.Text = "login" AndAlso TextBox2.Text = "password" Then
        Return True
    Else
        Return False
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use `BlnCorrectPassword` or `BlnCorrectLogin` with other Subs or Functions define them as global variables within that class as such

```
Public Class Form1

  Private BlnCorrectPassword as Boolean = False
  Private BlnCorrectLogin as Boolean = False

  Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LoginButton.Click

    If blncorrectlogin = True And blncorrectpassword = True Then
        MsgBox("This part is still being developed!") ' I will make this form close and open a new form.
    Else
        MsgBox("The login or password is incorrect, please try again.")
    End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    If TextBox1.Text = "login" Then
        BlnCorrectLogin = True
    End If

  End Sub

  Private Sub TextBox2_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox2.TextChanged

    If TextBox1.Text = "password" Then
        BlnCorrectPassword = True
    End If

  End Sub

End Class
```

EDIT: also you do not have to check the entered Text with every letter (TextChanged) as long as you do not use it, so just check the entered text when you click the LoginButton, in that way you don't need boolean variables and have two less Subs

Answer (score 0):

The code is still ugly and can definitely be simplified:

1.)  `blncorrectlogin = True And blncorrectpassword = True`    => You do not need to write = TRUE   ; AND  should not be used , use `AndAlso`.

2.)  `MsgBox` is deprecated. Use MessageBox.Show instead.

3.)  Textchanged can be concatenated. If like this:

```
 If TextBox1.Text = "login" Then
        BlnCorrectLogin = True
    End If
```

are totally crap and senseless.

4.) Strings should not be compared with "=" , use `.Equals` for that.

```
Option Strict On 'Always write this
Option Infer Off 'Always write this
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
    Private BlnCorrectPassword As Boolean = False
    Private BlnCorrectLogin As Boolean = False
    Private Sub TextBoxes_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged, TextBox2.TextChanged
        If sender.Equals(TextBox1) Then
            BlnCorrectLogin = TextBox1.Text.Equals("login")
        End If

        If sender.Equals(TextBox2) Then
            BlnCorrectPassword = TextBox2.Text.Equals("password")
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If Not (BlnCorrectLogin AndAlso BlnCorrectPassword) Then
            'do some stuff
            MessageBox.Show("The login or password is incorrect, please try again.")
            Exit Sub 'exit the sub
        End If
        'login data correct
        MessageBox.Show("This part is still being developed!")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Do you have a source for your claim that MsgBox is deprecated? Also, saying that somebody's code is "totally crap" is not really in the spirit of stackoverflow

Comment: Remove "Visual Basic" in My Project  -> References.

You will see that any functions that are deprecated and should not be used, will throw errors in your IDE.

Comment: No, you'll see all the functions that require the visual basic reference to be present throwing errors. The Microsoft.VisualBasic assembly is NOT deprecated